# Simplifying expressions containing binary variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, boolean-computation, binary

Consider an expression with two binary variables, $a,b\in\left\{ 0,1\right\} $, given by $F=(1-a-b)^{3}(1-b)$, with truth table:

```
{a,b}={0,0} -> F=1
{a,b}={0,1} -> F=0
{a,b}={1,0} -> F=0
{a,b}={1,1} -> F=0
```

A simpler way of writing this would be $F=G=(1-a-b)(1-b)$, which can be seen to produce the same truth table. However, if I try to do this with the following Mathematica input

```
FullSimplify[(1-a-b)^3 (1-b), {a, b} ∈ {0, 1}]
```

it doesn't do the trick. How can we do this in general and for more complicated expressions with more than 2 variables? I looked into [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69984/simplify-binary-expressions) question but it doesn't seem to be dealing with the same problem I'm presenting here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the assumptions that `a^2 == a` to do this:

```
Simplify[F, a^2==a && b^2==b]
```

> (-1 + a) (-1 + b)

Comment: Thank you. It's simple and it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier Q/A to which you linked provides a simpler form for `F` than what you proposed.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

binarySimplify[eq_, vars_] := Module[{rels, gb}, rels = (#^2 - # &) /@ vars;
  gb = GroebnerBasis[Join[{eq /. Equal -> Subtract}, rels], vars];
  Simplify@Thread[Complement[gb, rels] == 0]]

bs = binarySimplify[F == (1 - a - b)^3 (1 - b), {a, b, F}]

(* {1 + a b == a + b + F, a F == 0, b F == 0} *)
```

Working from the first equation

```
sol = Solve[bs[[1]], F][[1]] // Simplify

(* {F -> (-1 + a) (-1 + b)} *)
```

This definition of `F` is simpler than what you proposed and produces the same binary table.

```
Table[{a, b, F /. sol}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
  Prepend[#, {a, b, F}] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

So the simplified form for `F` is

```
F == (F /. sol)

(* F == (-1 + a) (-1 + b) *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked more carefully into this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is not exactly what you want, but may be useful for larger problems.

First, convert your function `F` to a boolean function `G`:

```
F[a_, b_] = (1 - a - b)^3 (1 - b);
# -> F @@ # & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]
(*    {{0, 0} -> 1, {0, 1} -> 0, {1, 0} -> 0, {1, 1} -> 0}    *)

G = # -> F @@ # & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 2] /. {0 -> False, 1 -> True} // BooleanFunction
(*    BooleanFunction[...]    *)
```

Now we can work with this [`BooleanFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanFunction.html) object: there are [many functions available](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BooleanComputation.html), for example

```
BooleanConvert[G][a, b]
(*    ! a && ! b    *)
```

(note that [`BooleanConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html) can output many different formats).

Try to convert the result back to an algebraic expression:

```
BooleanConvert[G][a, b] //. {! x_ -> 1 - x,
                             x_ && y_ -> x y,
                             x_ || y_ -> x + y - x y}
(*    (1 - a) (1 - b)    *)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this. How would you say this compares against Carl Woll's solution?

Comment: @almagy I don't really know, but I have a feeling that some simplifications may require stronger tools than $a^2=a$ and $b^2=b$. Boolean conversions may offer such stronger tools. Maybe you can show some examples where the results differ?

Comment: I'm using this to simplify a few expressions where some variables are kept as general parameters (so, it's a bit different from the example above where all variables are binary). I think your current solution doesn't handle such a situation, right?

Comment: Yes that's right.